# Accessing a local variable whose name comes from user input

Tags: python, list

i need to access strings using `raw_input`.

```
list1 = ["one","Two","three"]

list2 = ["1","2","3"]

while True:

        ip = raw_input("enter list: ")
        for i  in  ip:
                    print i
        break
```

When "list1" is given as input, it takes as string but not as list.
I need to access the list defined above.
I need a way to access the lists and print the list.

Comment: I think that what you are describing is [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval).

Comment: eval using user-supplied data == bad bad bad idea

Comment: You should not use `eval` instead of that use `literal eval`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval

Comment: @TanveerAlam: even literal_eval with user supplied input can be bad  for security (in the best case leak a lot of information).

Comment: I wanted to make sure that they use literal eval instead of eval but in this case that is bad idea. Thanks Paulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dict:

```
lists = {
    "list1": ["one","Two","three"],
    "list2": ["1","2","3"],       
}

while True:
    choice = raw_input("enter the list name: ")
    try:
        for item in lists[choice]:
            print item
    except KeyError:
        print "I never heard of any list named '{}'! Try again.".format(choice)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo for the answer.